# Moxios not using stubbed request

Tags: reactjs, axios, moxios

I am working through a udemy course and it's on the testing portion. In it, the instructor uses `moxios` to stub requests. However, it is not using the stubbed response. The stubbed response should only be returning 2 items, where as the actual API call returns 500. So my test is hitting the actual api and not the stubbed request. I have tried the call to mock the response in both the test and the beforeEach functions.

Any advice on what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
beforeEach(() => {
  moxios.install()
  moxios.stubRequest(
    'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
    {
      status: 200,
      response: [{ name: 'Fetched #1' }, { name: 'Fetched #2' }]
    }
  )
}) 

it('should fetch list of comments and display them', (done) => {
  const component = mount(
    <Root>
      <App />
    </Root>
  )


  component.find('#fetch-comments').simulate('click')

  moxios.wait(() => {
    component.update()
    expect(component.find('li').length).toEqual(2)

    done()
    component.unmount()
  }, 500)
});
```